# How do I check if the current key is in my dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I want to add a if statement to my code that will check if if the current key is in my dictionary. I have triesd to do this way:

```
if key in my_dict:
    pass
```

but it doesn't work. So how can I check if the current key is in my dictionary?

Thanks.

Comment: This is the correct way. How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: You'll need to show us some sample dictionary and key for which this doesn't work for us to say anything about this. If your literal code uses `pass` then your code won't show any output even if the test did return `True`, of course.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the key is not in the dictionary? It might be better to use `my_dict.get(key, default_value)` or `my_dict.setdefault(key, default_value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how you pythonically do it. You may be misunderstanding on what [`pass`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) does:

> The pass statement does nothing. It can be used when a statement is required syntactically but the program requires no action.

---

Just note, you may see something like `my_dict.has_key(key)`. This used to be used, but should not be used with python 2.7 and above.

Answer (score 0):

*pass is a null operation -- when it is executed, nothing happens*

**Your way is correct:**

```
>>> a
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> if 'a' in a:
...     print 'hello'
... 
hello
```

Some may want to do check this way. But don't do this.

```
>>> a = {'a': 1, 'b':2}
>>> a
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> a.keys()
['a', 'b']
>>> if 'a' in a.keys():
...     print 'hello'
... 
hello
>>>
```

**DON'T DO THIS!**

As Martijin pointed out, it's slow as you have to generate list first and again check list for the element.

Comment: Do **not** use `dict.keys()` here; use *just* `'a' in a`; using `'a' in a.keys()` is not only redundant, it is *slower* too as now you have to scan a list for the key. Testing against the dictionary is O(1) constant complexity, **much** cheaper than the O(n) complexity of a list scan.